# Syntax Error message with MySQL on the shell

Tags: command-line, apt, software-recommendation, mysql

I'm working with MySQL in zsh shell, and when I got an error, they didn't display what it is, but just where I could find it. In fact, I installed MySQL with the command `sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client`

[image]

**Questions :**

1. What kind of software could I use to work with the SQL language (and being more precise when I have an error)?
2. Is there exists a way to ask the terminal to be more precise?

Comment: You're lacking a comma between the two value tuples. The first error actually picked up the exact point where something was wrong.

Comment: @fuglede I knew that, but It is not always clear where is my error with the shell. That why I was wondering if there exists a software like PyCharm for the Python language or Xcode for the C++ language.

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity DataGrip exists, but it does not have a free version like PyCharm does.

Comment: @ThomasWard So for people who doesn't have a lot of money, we have to troubleshoot ourselves what is the problem?

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity Read my answer.  Ultimately the answer is "Yes", because the software you are using is not infallible so it may say a command works but it really won't (one of the things I state in my answer).  IDEs are good for helping spot major errors, but the more tricky errors it won't catch.  (Such as a query being correct but not being accurate enough because of datatype stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

> What kind of software could I use to work with the SQL language (and being more precise when I have an error)?

There are *many* SQL editors out there.  But since all SQL languages have their own basic nuances by flavor of SQL, let's focus on MySQL specifically.

For MySQL, I use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) (free, Oracle + Community, MySQL only) or [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) (not free, 30day trial, from JetBrains - the same company that produces PyCharm, multiple SQL flavors).

That said, they each have their own positive and negative aspects, of which would be a little hard for me to detail fully (and are for the most part out of the scope of what you're asking about from what I can tell).  This pros and cons issue also applies to all editors for SQL and ultimately becomes too broad - so we will focus on he two most common tools I use.

Specifically targeting your question though, neither are going to be "more precise" with the error message - the error message you saw was from the SQL client and server.  These IDEs and tools have their own built in syntax warning systems but they can't stop you from executing a syntactically correct command that doesn't actually work at the DB server itself.  (ALWAYS check your syntax yourself!)

> Is there exists a way to ask the terminal to be more precise?

No there isn't.  It's not the Terminal it's the MySQL client.  It isn't going to be any more precise than the error it gave you (this is why you have to read the queries being entered and syntax check them yourself, even if using a SQL editor/IDE).